# Firebase upload image from python to firebase-storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am find this docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#apis

Here is code from this docs

```
# Import gcloud
from google.cloud import storage

# Enable Storage
client = storage.Client()

# Reference an existing bucket.
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-existing-bucket')

# Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
zebraBlob = bucket.get_blob('zebra.jpg')
zebraBlob.upload_from_filename(filename='/photos/zoo/zebra.jpg')

# Download a file from your bucket.
giraffeBlob = bucket.get_blob('giraffe.jpg')
giraffeBlob.download_as_string()
```

In line `client = storage.Client()`

Said:

> Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credential and re-run the application

In the next step I am put

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = 'credentials.json'
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
```

Said:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine

And my final question is how to authenticate in Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved.

1.) You need to install https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

2.) Login inside cloud sdk with your gmail

3.) choose your firebase project

4.) put `gcloud auth application-default login` in console

5.) You can see credentials here

C:\Users\storks\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json

6.) For more info see  How the Application Default Credentials work

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials